# Flink TaskManager timeout?

Tags: apache-flink

I am running a Flink application (via Yarn) and it seems that randomly sometimes a task manager times out, here is the error:

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Heartbeat of TaskManager with id someId timed out.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster$TaskManagerHeartbeatListener.notifyHeartbeatTimeout(JobMaster.java:1610)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.heartbeat.HeartbeatManagerImpl$HeartbeatMonitor.run(HeartbeatManagerImpl.java:339)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ActorSystemScheduledExecutorAdapter$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ActorSystemScheduledExecutorAdapter.java:154)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:39)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:415)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

This happens 30-45 minutes after the job has started running. Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

Comment: How does the logs of the task manager looks like? Does the task-manager really dies? Or maybe he is under heavy load?

Answer (score 2):

The reason of this problem maybe the membory of JobManager is too small, try make it bigger

Comment: And how do we do that?

Comment: use the parameter `jobmanager.heap.size` at the file `flink-conf.yaml`